# Difference between "call: exit, echo" and "exit, echo" in batch file

Tags: batch-file, errorlevel

I've run into something confusing about the following batch code:

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set rootpath=%1

if '%1'=='' (
call :ERR
REM Exit /b 1001
) else (
exit /b 0
)
echo %errorlevel%
goto :EOF

:ERR
Exit /b 1001
```

and

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set rootpath=%1

if '%1'=='' (
REM call :ERR
Exit /b 1001
) else (
exit /b 0
)
echo %errorlevel%
goto :EOF

:ERR
Exit /b 1001
```

The only difference is that the first one uses call but the second one does not. Also, "echo" does not work on the second one. Can anyone help me understand these issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exit /b n` does two things. It sets `errorlevel` to `n` and then it returns to the next instruction in the routine that called the current routine.

So in the first - `call :err` sets `errorlevel` and returns to the `echo` which shows `errorlevel` as set, then proceeds to `:EOF` terminating the main routine.

**or**

terminates the main routine, having set `errorlevel` to 0

(depending on the `if` being true/false.)

In the second, the routine is terminated by the `exit` having set `errorlevel` to 1001 or 0 (depending on the `if` being true/false) and hence processing never reaches the `echo`.

Comment: Thanks Magoo, I think I'm starting to know how it works. The first call is subroutine, it returns to the main routine when exit. While the second one exit the main routine (if is not a subroutine). Is that correct?

Comment: Precisely. `exitexits the current routine. If it's a subroutine, then back to that routine's caller - and it may be many levels deep. If it's the main routine then that's the only routine left to terminate, so that's the one that get sterminated.